# How to calculate the confidence interval for the difference in predictions of the predict() R function?

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I wanted to ask about how to obtain a confidence interval for the difference between two predicted values estimated using predict() function.
For example,

```
data("cars", package = "datasets")

model <- lm(dist ~ speed, data = cars)
summary(model)

prediction1 = predict(model, newdata = list(speed = 12), interval = "confidence")
prediction1

prediction2 = predict(model, newdata = list(speed = 20), interval = "confidence")
prediction2

predict.dif = prediction2 - prediction1
predict.dif
```

what I got is
prediction1 = 29.60981 (lwr)24.39514 (upr)34.82448 
prediction2 = 61.06908 (lwr)55.24729 (upr)66.89088

and for the difference in prediction I get 
predict.diff =  31.45927 (lwr)30.85215 (upr)32.06639

My question is, in the previous example, I get the difference in predictions and R also subtracts the confidence intervals. Is it correct to subtract CIs this way? and why? and if not, I was wondering if there is a way to calculate such CI for the difference in predictions.

Thank you so much

Comment: Not correct to do addition or subtraction with CIs. Get some statistical advice.

Answer (score 1):

You pose a good question. In summary, we should not compute confidence intervals separately and then take the differences between their respective lower bounds and respective upper bounds.

**Why?**

To explain why, rather than getting too much into the math, I'll illustrate via an example:

1. Let's take your code snippet and just change `prediction2` to be a prediction when speed equals 13:

   ```
   data("cars", package = "datasets")
   model <- lm(dist ~ speed, data = cars)
   summary(model)

   prediction1 = predict(model, newdata = list(speed = 12), interval = "confidence")
   prediction1

   prediction2 = predict(model, newdata = list(speed = 13), interval = "confidence")
   prediction2

   predict.dif = prediction2 - prediction1
   predict.dif
   ```

   In this case your output would be:

   ```
         fit      lwr     upr
   1 3.932409 4.336198 3.52862
   ```

   But question yourself as to what we're doing here. You have a model of the form `dist = a + b*speed`. You then compute the model predictions at `speed = 12` and `speed = 13` and take the difference. So that gives `(a + b*13) - (a + b*12) = b`. Therefore, the confidence interval for the difference should be equal to the confidence interval for my parameter `b`. Let's check whether this is the case:

   ```
   confint(model)

                   2.5 %    97.5 %
   (Intercept) -31.167850 -3.990340
   speed         3.096964  4.767853
   ```
2. You can see that they are not equal. In your approach, the interval is `(4.336198, 3.52862)` vs the second approach where the interval is `(3.096964, 4.767853)`

If I find a good/easy to follow reference on the math behind this, I will link in the comments.

**Solution**

You can leverage the `contrast` package for this purpose. Using this package, we can call:

```
contrast(model, a = list(speed = 13), b = list(speed = 12))
```

and this would output the required confidence interval for the difference:

```
lm model parameter contrast

  Contrast      S.E.    Lower    Upper    t df Pr(>|t|)
1 3.932409 0.4155128 3.096964 4.767853 9.46 48        0
```

Getting back to your example, we can do

```
contrast(model, a = list(speed = 20), b = list(speed = 12))
```

to get

```
lm model parameter contrast

  Contrast     S.E.    Lower    Upper    t df Pr(>|t|)
1 31.45927 3.324102 24.77571 38.14283 9.46 48        0
```

Comment: Whew. When I started reading this answer I was sure that you were never going to get around to discussing contrasts. I think answering questions that fill in knowledge has regarding contrasts should probably be done on CrossValidated.com, but this is a good starting point.